# Angular2 route issue

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

While switching between the pages sometimes the text of page gets disappear but it comes back as I resize my page. Here is my code which I use to create routes. There is no error in console.

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path : '',
    component : CreateStrategyPage
  },
  {
    path : 'create-strategy',
    component : CreateStrategyPage,
  },
  {
    path : 'standard-strategy',
    component : StandardStrategy,
  },
])
```

Comment: I don't think so its route issue. It could be a problem of CSS.

Comment: There is no way we can answer such a question without a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: ok, I will try to reproduce the thing and update the question with plunker link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Some text tags would appear as invisible when navigating to pages, even though when inspecting DOM I could see text tags with text inside, as well as css associated with those elements. The problem appeared to be in a custom bold font, because when I tested site without it, the issue disappeared. What solved it for me was adding all text tags that were used throughout the site in a first header component which forced all text tags to render correctly. I made that text invisible and positioned those tags outside of the page so they don't interfere with the layout in any way.

Unfortunately, fix is a total hack so I will keep looking for a better solution but until then I have to apply some fix. I hope there is someone with a similar problem, who found or will find a nice solution